# How to get reference to parent object from child Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I am new to Salesforce.
I have Account (Master) and Keys (Detail).
I created a trigger on Keys. Now I need to get reference to the Account object  to do some manipulations.

I tried `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');` but it throws `System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object:`

Any help is greatly appreciated -Thank you

Comment: you will always have a reference to account from key @Sasi. Just use the field name that you gave to the master-detail field to Account. e.g. for the first record `Trigger.new[0].acc__c` if your field name is acc__c in Keys__c

Answer (score 2):

Here is some sample code that we usually use in triggers:

```
Set<Id> accountIds=new Set<Id> ();
//Prepare a set of all related account that are coming to key trigger
for(Key__c key:trigger.new){
    accountIds.add(key.Account__c);
    }
// Prepare a map that maps account id to Account Record. In SOQL put all fields that you may require for your logic
Map<Id,Account> accountMap=new Map<Id,Account> ([Select id,name from Account where id in :accountIds]);
for(Key__c key:trigger.new){
    Account relatedAccount=accountMap.get(key.Account__c);
    // here onwards you have key and it's related record. So put your trigger logic here

    }
```

I hope that helps.Please note that this is just one way of doing things, there could be alternative approaches as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the fields you need from the account.

An example:

```
Account temp = [SELECT Id, CreatedDate FROM Account WHERE Keys__c = IdOfCurrentKey];
```

You will have to rename the fields in my query to the correct fields in your org. Also change the `IdOfCurrentKey` to the correct `id` of the key, for example `key.Id`